# SFTP server gives connection error after reinstating deleted directories

Tags: sftp

Some time ago I set up an SFTP server which worked happily. I have a configuration like this in my ssh_config

```
# override default of no subsystems
#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server

Match User miscout
  # Force the connection to use SFTP and chroot to the required directory.
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  ChrootDirectory %h
  # Disable tunneling, authentication agent, TCP and X11 forwarding.
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no


Match Group sftp_users
  ChrootDirectory /mnt/reos-storage-1/sftp_data/%u
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  # Disable tunneling, authentication agent, TCP and X11 forwarding.
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

There is a user group `sftp_users` and a user named `sftpuser1`

Today, for some fun, I decided to accidentally delete the directory `/mnt/reos-storage-1/sftp_data`. I subsequently recreated the directory, and sub-directories, but now I cannot connect to the sftp server. I get an error like this:

```
$ sftp sftpuser1@<redacted>
sftpuser1@<redacted>'s password: 
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.41.113.249 port 22: Broken pipe
Connection closed
```

I can ssh into the machine as other users.

My guess is that I have the wrong permissions on this directory somehow, because it is the only thing I have changed. Currently permissions and ownership look like this:

```
[root] /mnt/reos-storage-1 $ ls -l sftp_data/
total 4
drwxrwx--x 3 root root 4096 Jun 23 13:22 sftpuser1
[root] /mnt/reos-storage-1 $ ls -l sftp_data/sftpuser1/
total 4
drwxrwx--x 3 sftpuser1 sftp_users 4096 Jun 23 13:23 upload
[root] /mnt/reos-storage-1 $ ls -l sftp_data/sftpuser1/upload/
total 864
drwxrwx--x 2 sftpuser1 sftp_users 884736 Jun 23 16:06 MiScout
```

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My answer was in the comments to an answer in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/889430/sftp-connection-closed-after-correct-password?rq=1)

The permissions on all parts of the Chroot directory parts need to be root.root.755. So in my case, this was the sftp_data and sftpuser1 directories.